# JScrollPane Not scrolling

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm printing a text that I scanned from a text file to a JPanel. The text is showing up, but it's not scrolling down. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
rFrame = new JFrame();
rFrame.setBounds(10, 10, 502, 502);
rFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


JPanel pan = new JPanel();
pan.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
pan.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
rFrame.getContentPane().add(pan);
pan.setEnabled(false);

JScrollPane scrollBar=new JScrollPane(pan,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                          JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);  

rFrame.add(scrollBar);

JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
area.setText(printToFrame()); //Function prints from text file
pan.add(area);
rFrame.add(pan);

rFrame.setVisible(true);
rFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
rFrame.getContentPane().add(pan);
rFrame.pack();

ClientWindow window = new ClientWindow();
window.rFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: pan is totally useless here. Add the text area directly to the scroll pane. Also, if I remember correctly, setEnabled does not work with nested components - but I might be wrong here.

Comment: You are correct and I deleted my answer due to this. WM, you need to study the Swing tutorials as all of this is explained there.

Comment: Also, study the source code of SwingSet2 that you find in the "demo" subdirectory of the JDK installation directory. Also: do not setLayout(null) unless you have a very good reason to (in this case you don't), scroll pane is not a scroll BAR, and don't add neither the text area nor the frame to the panel, because you already add the scroll pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not scrolling down because the dimensions of the `JPanel` is not larger than the viewport of the `JScrollPane`. You either have to increase the dimensions of the `JPanel` by calling `*Object name*.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(int w, int h))`, **OR** do it the proper way by displaying the text inside a **`JTextArea`**, which is a component made for this purpose.

Ex:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ta);

    // disables editing
    ta.setEditable(false);

    // enable line wrap to wrap text around
    ta.setLineWrap(true);

    // words will not be cut off when wrapped around
    ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    // displays the text you read in
    ta.append( *text you read in* );
}
```

Oracle has a page on how to use [JTextAreas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), and you can also take a look at the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) for other methods to use

Comment: Rather then using set size, you should return appropriate values from preferredSize or use the Scrollable interface ... IMHO